# Is it better to use fewer tables with more columns or vice versa?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm trying to figure out how to determine the best balance in structuring a database.  I want to be able to store the information from several different forms submitted by different people, sometimes multiple times (such as a yearly update).  I'm stuck between having a different table for each form, or a combination of form and element definition and element value tables.

Example A: There are three types of form with different information, so there are four tables, [FormA], [FormB], and [FormC] that each have the data associated with their respective forms, all FKed to [Customers].

Example B: Same three forms, but this time there are five different tables.  [FormDescriptions] defines the form names, types, etc and has three entries, one for each form.  [Forms] FKs to [Customers] and [FormDescriptions] and uses these in combination with the submission date to distinguish individual submissions. [FormElements] defines all the elements from the three forms, with a FK on FormDescriptions and a unique elementID.  [ElementValues] FKs to [FormElements] and [Forms] and stores the value of the selected element on the selected form.

My question is, is one of these methods inherently better than the other, and if not, in which situations is each better than the other?  As much why or why not that you want to include is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"My question is, is one of these methods inherently better than the other, and if not, in which situations is each better than the other? As much why or why not that you want to include is appreciated."

Your option two is (your personalized variant of) the EAV antipattern.  If you use this, and you expect (now or later) the system to do *anything* "intelligent" with the data, you'll find yourself in serious trouble.  And things as basic as "rigorous data validation to catch data entry errors" already qualifies as "intelligent".  So only use it if you can reasonably anticipate that the system will *only* be used for *just merely storing* the data, and that it will be unlikely for there ever to be a request to start processing/manipulating the data in "intelligent ways".

If you ever run into requests to start doing "intelligent" things with an EAV database, you'll find that whatever development time you thought you gained by working from a super duper generic information model, you'll lose orders of magnitude more time coding all the "intelligent" things required, i.e. reinstating the data structures in code that you refused to reflect in the DB.

Googling for "EAV antipattern" (try to locate the book by Bill Karwin) should provide you with more than enough info on why not to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 factors in consideration here

1. Performance
2. flexibility

If your system is such that it will require you to add more forms in future frequently.. method 2 is better. You won't have to add additional tables or columns. Your forms are data driven. It will add little overhead for generating forms and saving as key value pairs.

On other hand if your system won't require many changes to forms first method can work.

Also consider usage of data after forms are submitted. Are you going to run analytics, reports on this data? Are these reports specific to forms? That will favor method 1.